# How to persist type List<String> in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to persist   List ,  I failed to do.
Entity :

```
@Entity(name = "carepost")
@Table(name = "carepost")
public class CarePost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long idCarePost;

    private String code ;


     @ElementCollection
     @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
      private  List<@NotBlank String> service ;
```

and this is the API I save throw :

```
@PostMapping("/addcarepost")
public ResponseEntity<?> createCarePost(@RequestBody CarePost carePost){



    carePost.setCareserviceId(carePost.getCareserviceId());

    List<String> lstServices= new ArrayList<>();

    carePost.getService().forEach(item -> {
        lstServices.add(item);
    });

    carePost.setService(lstServices);


    carePostService.save(carePost);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("CarePost registered successfully!"));
}
```

I had error here :

[image]

Please any help can't fins solution for it

Error :

[image]

Postman request :

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details like the exception or the exact error, which you get?

Comment: I edited the post can u check please

Comment: You want `carePost.setService(lstServices);` **only**. Remove the foreach. You are not looping over the correct items

Comment: I delete it but still same error

Comment: `carePost.getService()` is null. If you dont use the getter for anything, then you shouldn't get the same error

Comment: Besides, we dont know what your request body actually looks like to the API

Comment: I edited the post can u check please